# azure devops cross domain

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have two domains on our network : domain A and domain B with a trust between them. We created AuereDevops 2019 update 1.1 server as on premise in domain A and want users from Domain B to access and use this AzureDevops. Since this AzureDevops server was set to work via port 80 (not 8080), we opened access in Domain A to port 80, and also port 443 of this server (although we defined to use http not https).

Following, we can connect via web access from Domain B to the server in Domain A, but cannot do so from team explorer in visual studio, from a computer in domain A. The team explorer within Visual Studio shows only the name of the server in domain B but no siblings within it (i.e. no team projects to connect).

Another cross domain issue occurs when assigning Work Item to a user in domain A - no email is received to notify about it. Only when explicitly sending mail from the work item windows, the email is received.

Can u pls advise how to overcome this problem ? Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found where the root of the problem is and fixed it as follows.

The reason why couldn't connect from visual studio in domain A to AzureDevOps server in domain B, was because visual studio does not support suffix ".domainB" for the tfs server. We defined a DNS mapping for the server in domain A, and this resolved the issue. Now connection from VSTS is done by directly providing the server name of Domain B.