# TFS is not accessible from Visual Studio from cross domain

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs, active-directory

Team Foundation Server (TFS) accessible via the web but not through Visual Studio, from Cross Domain. Getting attached Error when trying from Visual Studio.

[image]

I check the port 443 via telnet the connection is opened and working fine.
Checked the URL from web it is working fine.

Comment: What's your version for VS and TFS? If the issue persists after installing the certificate, please clear [cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48618076/14996050) and signout account on VS. Launch VS again for a check.

Comment: The VS version is 2012, and the TFS version is 2017.3. I already cleared the cache, but the issue still persists.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, please connect the TFS from same domain, will it succeed?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine on the same domain. When I am trying to access it from another domain, we are facing this issue. On the other domain, it is also working on the web, but when we are trying to connect from Visual Studio, we get the mentioned error.

Comment: If it's successful to connect with same vs and TFS on same domain, but only failed on different domain, it's recommended to double check the certificate installed.

Comment: I double-checked the certificate and I imported it as well on dev machine from where I am connection VS. Is there any specific thing I need to check please let me know I will check.

Comment: As per the [similar ticket answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592172/azure-devops-cross-domain), you could need to create the DNS mapping resolve the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the TLS and now it works fine.
Run the below command via powershell or CMD.

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be a certificate issue. Check the certificate icon on your web browser.
Import your certificate to the Trusted Root if it highlights this issue: [Installing the trusted root certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate), [Azure DevOps Server Certificate options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/websitesettings?view=azure-devops-2022&source=recommendations#certificate-options)

Example on web browser:

[image]

Comment: Certificate is imported but still it is not working